# Loading pictures in Android

Tags: android, listview

What is the best practice for loading images from the Web into a ListView?

Do I have to load them first into SQLite database or should I load them directly into a ListView?

And also after clicking an item in the ListView I have to show the same image in another activity. Is it the right way to pass this image to another activity or it is better to load it from Web / SQLite once again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here [Lazy loading of images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012)

Loading them directly into the listview will make scrolling in it slow, as it will reload them everytime they get visible.

Answer (score 0):

do that Google recommended http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html